# Submitting forms in multiple iframe with single submit button

Tags: jsp, iframe, form-submit

I have a scenario where in i need to submit `multiple jsp forms` that are in `multiple iframes` with `single submit` button. Is it possible to do so?. I tried various ideas but none of them is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple forms by using the below command :

```
document.forms["your form name"].submit();
```

On click of the first button you can call a method which manually does the submit for all the forms for you :)

hope this helps.